# Do bad questions get tracked?

Tags: support

Basically, should I be worried about how many of my questions were rejected? Is there some sort of "mod closed 5 of your question so we're banning you for a week" type of punishments?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Sort of; given enough downvoted, closed and/or deleted questions, you can get an automatic question ban. Good (upvoted) questions will compensate for this. You'll first get warned by the system; if you continue posting poor questions, you might end up getting banned and only be able to post one question every six months. For details, see [What can I do when getting "We are no longer accepting questions/answers from this account"?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/86997/295232) on Meta Stack Exchange.

Answer (score 7):

I know you've already chosen Glorfindel's answer but there are some points I'd like to address.

First is that I think you are proceeding from a false assumption.  First of all, you've only asked three questions, and one of them is this Meta question. Of the other two, only one was closed. The other is still open. I read the closed question, and disagree with the closure rationale, so have voted to reopen it.

Just so you're aware, closing a question is not the community's way of saying "we hate your question, we hate you, we're rejecting you, so go away with your stupidness!"  Not at all!  It is the community's way of saying "we think there is a specific issue with your query so we are temporarily closing it to give you an opportunity to edit and make it a better fit for our forum." Even though I've voted to reopen, you are certainly welcome to review how you wrote your question and edit it, perhaps with some conditions or expectations that would no longer be seen by others as "opinion based". If you did that, chances are good the people who closed your question would turn right around and vote to reopen.

Right now your average looks bad -- 50% closure rate! Oh, no! We're going down in flames!  Come back and revisit this Meta question after you've written at least 20 questions. If your average is still 50%, then maybe we can look at how you're writing your questions and work on improving the mechanics. We could get you to put those closed questions into the Sand Box where folks can help you improve them.

I'd say that if you wrote three more questions and they ended up as well received as your magic ~ technology query, then you've nothing to worry about.

I see that you're writing a web comic, so hopefully we can be of more help to you in the future! By the way, I like the look of your art and will keep an Eye on your comic!  You might consider joining the [Universe Factory](https://medium.com/universe-factory), which is our local creative outlet publication area. You could write a story, advertise your web comic, write an article about the conjunction of world building and web comic production.